# What is 'module_number' as argument to zend_register_list_destructors_ex

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm writing a php extension and need to register a resource. I have been reading on how to do this and all examples I have seen pass a variable

```
module_number
```

as the last parameter to

```
zend_register_list_destructors_ex(NULL, NULL, DESCRIPTOR_NAME, module_number);
```

None of the documents I found explain what 'module_number' is. I tried to use that variable name in my call to the function and I got the following error:

```
ext\niklos\niklos.c(132) : error C2065: 'module_number' : undeclared identifier
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\Bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

What is the last argument to the function call supposed to be or what is 'module_number' as all other examples have been using? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

zend_register_list_destructors_ex **must** be called inside a PHP_MINIT function registered by your extension

If you look at the macro definition for PHP_MINIT it expands to

int zm_startup_##module(int type, int module_number TSRMLS_DC)

with ##module being the string name of your module

module_number is an integer passed into the startup function by the engine

that module number is the id that PHP keeps around internally to identify the extension when it is registered

The shmop extension is a good example of a simple extension using resources

http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/shmop/shmop.c#137

That is the implementation of calling zend_register_list_destructors_ex

http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/shmop/shmop.c#96

and here is where the MINIT function is registered